# Blender 2.79: How do I animate UV Maps?

Tags: animation, uv, keyframes, uv-image-editor, unity

So I'm working on a game in Unity, and it involves this character, Short Circuit.

[image]

The eye texture you see here contains all of the expressions I made, and I'm thinking I'll animate them with the Offset function in Properties along with the rest of the body, as seen in the second set of images.

[image]

[image]

However, I'm finding that even though I keyframe the offset, the eyes just remain in one expression until I manually change them. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: if i was doing it i would do this part in unity and as a sprite sheet its so much easier but in blender i cant think of having a texture coordinate with mapping and playing with the mapping node : a value connected to math multiply feed it to combine xyz and give it to location of the map node and somehow finding the right multiplier that changes by incrementing an integer

Comment: If 2.79 doesn't have an actual mapping node, I can resurrect my hand mangled mapping nodes for you.  Can you keyframe the input value node in 2.79?

Comment: in blender you can do this with drivers . one way at least if that is your question i can explain how but in unity you can have an animated sprite and the character animation and sync them in one script

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&index=64) covers face rigging in Blender 2.7 using a texture image and UV mapping.